# Holographic Remoting breaks in play mode with XRInputSubsystem errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I use Unity (2019.4 LTS) for developing an application for Microsoft HoloLens 2 as the target platform. To do so, I added MRTK (Version v2.5) to my project to use some of the libraries. I regularly get errors in the console that look like this:

**[XRInputSubsystem] A device disconnection with the id 2000000037 has been reported but no device with that id was connected.**

It seems to happen somewhat randomly. At first, I thought it was disconnecting or something, but then I realized it was just pausing Unity, and I can click 'play' several times to bypass them. This workaround is annoying and slows me down though. Does anyone have an idea for solving this issue?

Comment: We always recommend the latest MRTK version as the best version to develop the MR app, and the current recommendation is to use MRTK 2.7.2. Please review the [Upgrade Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/updates-deployment/updating?view=mrtkunity-2021-05) for guidance on how to upgrading your project.

Comment: Besides, could you provide more detail about which XR pipeline (legacy XR pipeline or XR SDK or OpenXR)  are you using? Microsoft’s current recommended Unity configuration for HoloLens 2 and Windows Mixed Reality development is Unity 2020.3 LTS with the latest Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT Thanks for your answer. I tried the last version of MRTK 2.7.2 with the last version of Unity 2021.1.24. Unfortunately, I still have this problem. Could you please let me know how I can realize which XR pipeline I am using? Thanks again.

Comment: Has XR Plugin Management been installed in your project? You can check whether there is XR Plugin Management in the list of Project Settings to know. If it has been installed, please make sure the OpenXR and Microsoft HoloLens feature set boxes under XR Plugin Management have been select. For more information, please see: [Setting up your XR configuration
](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/xr-project-setup?tabs=openxr)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error only by increasing the bandwidth of my Internet network. This error happened when my Internet bandwidth was 9MB per second. Now, I use a stronger bandwidth of about 70MB per second and I do not see the same error at all.